# How to redirect submit to parent window using Wix Iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, velo

Hi can anyone assist me with what I need to do to get the url associated with the submit button to open in the parent window?

I am using the Wix html editor to add the code but for some reason upon submitting the returnURL only displays inside the Iframe and does not direct the url to the entire window?

Any assistance would be MAJORLY appreciated!

```
    <input type='text' style='display:none;' name='returnURL' 
    value='https://www.MYURL.co.uk/' > </input>
       <!-- Do not remove this code. -->
        <style>
        #crmWebToEntityForm tr , #crmWebToEntityForm td { 
            padding-left:0px;
             padding-right:0px;
            border-spacing:0px;
            border-width:0px;
            }
    </style>
    <table style='width:260px;background-color:#3a3b3f;background-color:ffffff;color:black'> 
  <tr></tr> 
  <tr>
  <td style='width:100%;'><input type='text' placeholder="First Name" maxlength='40'  
  style='width:260px; height:50' name='First Name'></input></td>
  <td style='width: 100%;'></td></tr><tr><td style='width:260px;'>
  <input type='text'placeholder="Last Name" maxlength='80'  style='width:100%; height:50' 
  name='Last Name'></input></td><td style='width: 260px;'></td></tr>
  <tr>
  <td style='width:100%;'><input type='text' placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength='30'  
  style='width:260px; height:50' name='Phone'></input></td>
  <td style='width: 100%;'></td></tr><tr><td style='width:100%;'><input type='text' 
  placeholder="Email Address" maxlength='100'  style='width:260px; height:50' name='Email'> 
  </input></td>
   <td style='width: 100%;'></td></tr><tr><tr style='display:none;' ><td style='width:260px'>
        <select style='width:260px;box-sizing:border-box;' name='Lead Source'>
            <option value='-None-'>-None-</option>
            <option value='Advertisement'>Advertisement</option>
        <option value='Cold&#x20;Call'>Cold Call</option>
            <option value='Employee&#x20;Referral'>Employee Referral</option>
        <option value='External&#x20;Referral'>External Referral</option>
        <option value='Partner'>Partner</option>
        <option value='Public&#x20;Relations'>Public Relations</option>
        <option value='Trade&#x20;Show'>Trade Show</option>
        <option selected value='Web&#x20;Form'>Web Form</option>
        <option value='Search&#x20;Engine'>Search Engine</option>
        <option value='Facebook'>Facebook</option>
        <option value='Twitter'>Twitter</option>
        <option value='Online&#x20;Store'>Online Store</option>
        <option value='Seminar&#x20;Partner'>Seminar Partner</option>
        <option value='Web&#x20;Download'>Web Download</option>
    </select></td><td style='width: 100%;'></td></tr><tr><tr style='display:none;' ><td 
style='width:100%;' ><input type='text' style='width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;'  
maxlength='255' name='LEADCF1' value='ContractorPeople'></input></td><td style='width: 
260px;'></td></tr>
<tr><td style='width:100%;'><textarea maxlength='32000'  style='width:100%; height:80' 
name='Description'style='width:260px;box-sizing:border-box;'>&nbsp;</textarea></td>

<tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align:left;padding-top:15px;font-size:16px;'>
  <button id="formssubmit">SUBMIT QUERY</button><style type="text/css" type="submit" 
action="https://www.thecontractorpeople.co.uk" >

  #formssubmit { 
 background-color: #3a3b3f;
 padding: .5em;
 -moz-border-radius: 5;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Avenir';
 font-size: 18px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border:color:#ffffff;
}

#formssubmit:hover {
 border: none;
 background: #9799A4;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
#formssubmit {
  float: left; 
  margin-left:
  margin-bottom:4px;
  </style> <script>
      var mndFileds=new Array('Last Name');
      var fldLangVal=new Array('Last Name'); 
        var name='';
        var email='';
      function checkMandatory204987000000227471() {
        for(i=0;i<mndFileds.length;i++) {
          var fieldObj=document.forms['WebToLeads204987000000227471'][mndFileds[i]];
          if(fieldObj) {
            if (((fieldObj.value).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')).length==0) {
             if(fieldObj.type =='file')
                { 
                 alert('Please select a file to upload.'); 
                 fieldObj.focus(); 
             return false;
            } 
        alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be empty.'); 
          fieldObj.focus();
          return false;
        }  else if(fieldObj.nodeName=='SELECT') {
         if(fieldObj.options[fieldObj.selectedIndex].value=='-None-') {
            alert(fldLangVal[i] +' cannot be none.'); 
            fieldObj.focus();
            return false;
           }
        } else if(fieldObj.type =='checkbox'){
         if(fieldObj.checked == false){
            alert('Please accept  '+fldLangVal[i]);
            fieldObj.focus();
            return false;
           } 
         } 
         try {
             if(fieldObj.name == 'Last Name') {
            name = fieldObj.value;
            }
        } catch (e) {}
        }

    }
    document.getElementById('formsubmit').disabled=true;
}

    }
</script>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the URL to the parent page using the HTML component's onMessage function (https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.HtmlComponent.html#onMessage)

Then on your page have a event listener for when the HTML component sends a message, then grab the url from it and redirect it using wixLocation.to()

```
export function html1_message(event) {
    let url = event.data;
    wixLocation.to(`${url}`);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shan thanks for this info, Im not to sure how to implement the above code and the onMessage function into my HTML but I will take a look!